# Post Processing Stack Ambient Occlusion stops working on runtime with Unity, VRTK, and SteamVR on the HTC Vive

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive, ambient, occlusion, vrtk

When adding ambient occlusion from the Post Processing Stack asset onto the SteamVR camera, it works fine until I hit the play button (SteamVR is enabled for this as the VRTK manager automatically disables it). After that it disappears. I noticed that if I move the post processing behavior script in the component hierarchy during runtime, the ambient occlusion works.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: I found that this is true for all of the post processing stack effects, not just the ambient occlusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I found that adding the Post Processing Behavior script to the CameraRig gameobject fixes the issue.
Not sure why though.*

**Edit:** This also makes the controllers not visible. Not a valid solution.

**Edit** I found that adding a camera with the Post Processing Stack script as a child of cameraRig gameobject fixes the issue. It seems that something in the eye gameobject is causing the incompatibility.